# How to add to new ArrayList without a conversion error?

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean, void

I keep getting an error saying that void/boolean cannot be converted to ArrayList . However, I am passing the index of the largest quakeData and a QuakeEntry should be returning to be added to my new ArrayList answer. I do not know how to fix this.

```
public ArrayList<QuakeEntry>getLargest(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> quakeData, int howMany) {
    ArrayList<QuakeEntry> answer = new ArrayList<QuakeEntry>();
    int bigIndex = indexOfLargest(quakeData);
    answer = answer.add(quakeData.get(bigIndex));

    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to return the `answer` list:

```
public ArrayList<QuakeEntry>getLargest(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> quakeData, int howMany) {
    ArrayList<QuakeEntry> answer = new ArrayList<QuakeEntry>();
    int bigIndex = indexOfLargest(quakeData);
    answer.add(quakeData.get(bigIndex));

    return answer;
}
```

The [`List#add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) method returns a `boolean` value, which would be true if the addition were successful.  It doesn't make sense to try to assign the result of `List#add` to your `answer` list.  But, in your case, the method requires that you return a `List<QuakeEntry>`, so just do that.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am trying to return an ArrayList in order from the biggest to smallest quake which varies depending on howMany are asked for. I don't understand how to take a <QuakeEntry> from quakeData and put it into a new ArrayList. I need to return my answer as an ArrayList. However once I get QuakeEntry by using the .get() method I can no longer add it to answer.

Comment: Did you actually try my suggested code?  I don't see any reason why it should not at least run.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been in my own head. I guess I was using the add method incorrectly. I really appreciate your help.